# Use Android Uri.builder to append query with no value

Tags: android, uri

I want to append a query with no assigned value to my Uri and I want to use [Android built in classes from android.net package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) to create the Uri.

Wanted: `http://www.example.com/path?foo=bar&flag` where `flag` does not have a value (just exist)

```
import android.net.Uri;

[...]

final Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
               .scheme("http")
               .authority("www.example.com")
               .path("path")
               .appendQueryParameter("foo", "bar");
               .appendQueryParameter("flag", null);
Log.d("SO", builder.build().toString());
```

Gives `http://www.example.com/path?foo=bar&flag=null` where `flag` is assigned null :(

Comment: Try `.appendQueryParameter("foo", "bar&flag");`

Comment: you cannot do that with `appendQueryParameter`, sorry... - you have to build "query" with your hands and call `query(String query)`